# Angular velocity and axis of rotation

Tags: vectors, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

If the angular velocity is along the axis of rotation, then why angular velocity has different components in space and body axis. Let's say $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ is the angular velocity, if it is in the direction of the axis of rotation $\mathbf{n}$; and $R$ is the matrix rotation that transform the space axis to the body axis then, the angular velocity in the body axis is

$$R \boldsymbol{\omega} = \omega R\mathbf{n} = \omega \mathbf{n} = \boldsymbol{\omega}  $$

$R\mathbf{n} = \mathbf{n}$ by definition of axis of rotation.

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse the physical concept with the mathematical representation.

The components of the vectors differ because the basis vectors (unit directions) are different. That is what the rotation matrix does, it converts from one set of basis vectors to another.

But the rotational velocity of the body exists as a concept regardless of the basis vectors used. Only when expressed as a vector the basis vectors need to be specified.

In terms of components and in general $$ \mathbf{R}\, \boldsymbol{\omega} \neq \boldsymbol{\omega} $$

It is better to indicate what basis vectors are used because then

$$ \mathbf{R}\, \boldsymbol{\omega}|^{\rm body} = \boldsymbol{\omega}|^{\rm world} $$

This is because the orientation of the body may not coincide with the spin axis. Only in the very specific case where a body is pinned and $\mathbf{R} = \mathrm{rot}(\boldsymbol{n}, \theta)$ along a fixed axis, then $\boldsymbol{\omega} = \boldsymbol{n} \dot{\theta}$ and thus by definition

$$ \mathbf{R}\, \boldsymbol{n} = \boldsymbol{n} $$

In general, the instantaneous axis of rotation has a direction defined by $\boldsymbol{\omega}$

$$ \boldsymbol{n} = \frac{ \boldsymbol{\omega} }{\| \boldsymbol{\omega} \|} $$

or the decomposition into magnitude and direction

$$ \boldsymbol{\omega} = \omega\, \boldsymbol{n} $$

In general thus the rotation matrix is not defined by a single fixed axis rotation, but by three rotations (Euler angles) about fixed axes, or one rotation about an arbitrary axis $\boldsymbol{u}$

$$ \mathbf{R} = \mathrm{rot}(\boldsymbol{u}, \theta)$$

In general, the rotation axis is not parallel to the $\boldsymbol{u} \neq \boldsymbol{n}$ spin axis. One exists when describing angles and orientations and the other when describing angular velocities.

This is analogous to the linear position $\boldsymbol{r}$ and velocity $\boldsymbol{v}$ where the two vectors are parallel only under special cases.

Answer (score 0):

The body axes are fixed in the rotating body and are usually taken as the principal axes. The space axes are fixed in an inertial system and are a different set of axes.  Since the two sets of axes are different, the angular velocity has different components along the axes.

(In general, the angular velocity may not be fixed in either magnitude or direction.)

See *Mechanics* by Symon, and *Classical Mechanics* by Goldstein for details.